# COM+ application package hangs - Production Crash

Tags: com, vb6

We have existing VB6 COM+ application running on multiple servers.

Recently, we have implemented change to integrate COM+ application with a .Net class library (to consume IBM ESB services).

**Problem**

The application stops responding all of a sudden. This happens intermittently

Whenever this situation happens we see some COMponets hanging in the COM+ package. That application call time for some of the components becomes to high.

We need to shut down and restart the COM package to make the application work.

We have checked the code for infinite loops, etc, but haven't found any.

How to debug this situation? We are not able to reproduce this in development or test environment. Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Can you provide some code

Comment: Find what is different between the test and the production environment? Get a better test environment that exactly reproduces the production?

Comment: Take a process dump and analylze it with Visual Studio or WinDbg. But the problem is too broad to be in one SO question.